# Django Sending Email Using Signals

Tags: django-signals

I'm testing django signal to send an email but I'm getting the following error.

'list' object has no attribute 'splitlines'

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Booking)

def new_booking(sender, instance, **kwargs):
if instance.firstname:
    firstname = [instance.firstname]
    # lastname = [instance.lastname]
    email = [instance.email]
    # phone = [instance.phone]
    subject = [instance.service]
    # date = [instance.date]
    # time = [instance.time]
    # fullname = [firstname + lastname]
    # details = [service]
    send_mail(firstname, subject, email,
              ['cmadiam@abc.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Do i miss something?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Got this working... if someone needs it... here's the code...

```
from .models import Booking

@receiver(post_save, sender=Booking)
def new_booking(sender, instance, **kwargs):
if instance.firstname:
    firstname = (instance.firstname)
    email = (instance.email)
    subject = (instance.service)
    send_mail(firstname, subject, email,
              ['cmadiam@abc.com'], fail_silently=False)
```