# Django send email reminder based on date how to?

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm using a Windows OS and have a model where users selects a date. Based on the date I want to send an email to the user at an interval of 10, 25, 35, 50 days.
I checked celery but now celery isn't supported on windows....can someone please help me with it..how to setup this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use signals: "The Django Signals is a strategy to allow decoupled applications to get notified when certain events occur."
So you set up a function that, based on a event, will generate an email.
You have plenty of examples on the web. For instance:

[Django Sending Email Using Signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59406326/django-sending-email-using-signals)

https://anymail.readthedocs.io/en/stable/sending/signals/

https://stackabuse.com/using-django-signals-to-simplify-and-decouple-code/

So how do you create the event? Someone asked on stackoverflow this question and you will find a nice approach:

[Django Timed Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377661/django-timed-events) and

[Set up a scheduled job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/set-up-a-scheduled-job)

In a nutshell, you create a custom management command and use cron (on Linux) or at (on Windows) to run your command at the required times. Thus you avoid celery.